# Yeoman 'yo webapp' runs, but no files created in directory

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've got Node and Yeoman installed, after going down a wrong path or two (Homebrew install, sudo for Yeoman), I then installed Node correctly with the package on their site (mac os x, mavericks) and reinstalled Yeoman without sudo.

But I think I've borked things up a bit, somehow.  After installing the webapp generator (which also worked fine), I go into a yeomantest folder on my Desktop and try to 'yo webapp', but while everything runs and Yeoman says it worked, there is nothing in the folder.

It's creating these files somewhere (because when I run it again, it asks me whether to overwrite or not), I just can't figure out where or why.

Possibly it's because Node installed here: "PATH=/Users/xpeeblix/.node/bin/:$PATH"

Any ideas on how to fix this or what's going on?  I'll be eternally grateful and name my first born after you.

Please supply name with answer to collect prize.

Comment: I'm not sure what this, "name with answer" thing is, but the "prize" on SE is to vote up and accept their answer. No name required.

Comment: Just a bit o' humor Wesley.  Answer checked, but not enough points to upvote, alas.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Chances are when working with your broked setup you created a `.yo-rc.json` file in a parent directory of `/yeomantest/`.

Yeoman uses `.yo-rc.json` to determine the root of your project. This allows users to run `yo n` command from anywhere inside the project directory and have them applied from the correct location.

So, walk up your directory tree and try to find a `.yo-rc.json` file; then delete it. On OSx and Windows, `.named` files are hidden by default, you may need to make them visible from your system configuration.

Comment: Interesting, when I do a find for .yo-rc.json, I find it in two places.

/Users/xpeeblix//.npm/yeoman-generator/0.13.4/package/test/fixtures/dummy-project/.yo-rc.json

and

/Users/xpeeblix//.yo-rc.json

Comment: I hope it's a boy, naming a girl Simon seems wrong.

You win the prize, my friend.  After deleting both, yo webapp scaffolds out my yeomantest directory.

Many thanks!

Now, as a follow-up, do you think my installation is still hopelessy borked or can I continue with Node/Yeoman set up this way?

Comment: Your setup looks ok from the few things I can see. You can run `yo doctor` to get a fast basic checkup of the environment variables Yeoman uses. Also, know you brought up a discussion and we'll probably implement contextual notification to help user troubleshoot these kinds of errors: https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/497

Comment: For the record, [Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks alright!
Thanks again Simon, I searched extensively for any clues to this question, to no avail.  Hopefully this thread can help someone else, as well.

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
yo doctor
```

It shows if everything look alright

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root

Everything looks all right!
```

Remove .bowerrc and .yo-rc.json files from the root directory then run yo to generate files in the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues with `.bowerrc` and `.yo-rc.json` just run:

`rm ~/.bowerrc` and `rm ~/.yo-rc.json` and then run `yo doctor` again. If the issue was fixed `yo doctor` will tell you.

Yo was intalling my angular project in the root. Updating Yo didn't do anything for me but removing the previous files fixed it. I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a .yo-rc.json file in a parent directory? if so delete it. it might be hidden